# jQuery Mobile click event using ajax navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the jQuery mobile library (JQM) but am having an issue with a jQuery click event.

By default, JQM uses ajax page transitions to change the DOM. I have a search icon in the header where I want to add a simple click event:

```
$("#search-toggle").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

This will work only for the home page as subsequent pages are all ajax/dom manipulations.

e.g. It wont work on

```
www.test.com/#/about
```

but would work on

```
www.test.com/about
```

I want to retain the page transitions (ajax naviagation). How can I however get a simple click event to work with every new 'page'.

A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorted it:

```
$('#search-toggle').live('click', function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: in fact needed 'tap' instead of 'click'

Comment: If you are using the beta, you may also want to look at the vclick event.  It is supposed to automaticly use the most appropriate method depending on the platform in order to react as fast as possible